# Is it possible to install the arcgis Python module into QGIS's Python?

Tags: qgis, python, ssl

I am trying to install the arcgis Python module from the cheeseshop into my QGIS 3.28.3.

The first hurdle I have to overcome is the missing SSL module in QGIS. I went through the OSGeo4w setup and installed it, but `pip.exe install arcgis` or in fact any other 3rd party module still triggers the following:

*WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.*

*WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/arcgis/*

Because I'm desperate I checked the Python environment of QGIS 3.28.3 and installed a 64bit Python 3.9.5. Here I installed the arcgis module and went through the list of newly installed modules in the site-packages.

I copied those that did not exist already in the QGIS Python and now a

`from arcgis.gis import GIS`

does work in the QGIS Python prompt. However, when I want to authenticate myself against my Enterprise Portal, the following line triggers the OAuth in a browser window, but never generates the possibility to paste the authentication string into it.

`gis = GIS('https://server/portal', client_id='my_client_id')`

Instead QGIS becomes inaccessible and I have to kill the program.

I tried the same on the command line, where I get the expected prompt for *Enter code obtained on signing in using SAML:*.

However, after supplying my authentication code I am getting the following error:

*File "C:\path\to\Python39\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis_impl_con_connection.py", line 1494, in post
raise requests.exceptions.SSLError(
requests.exceptions.SSLError: Please set verify_cert=False due to encountered SSL error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my_server_url', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /portal/sharing/rest/oauth2/token (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))*

The attempt to authenticate myself with my credentials leads to the same error message.

**EDIT**
I followed the advice in the error message and added `verify_cert=False` to the command

`gis = GIS('https://server/portal', client_id='my_client_id', verify_cert=False)`,

yet, the error message is still the same.

In the end I am running circles around the SSL problem with QGIS. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: As I know (I am new to QGIS), you can use Python console in QGIS. I do not think you can install the arcgis Python module into QGIS